# clear textbox but giving error using java script

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to clear textbox by using this javascript code:

`document.getElementById("txtUnit").value = "";`

or:

`document.getElementById("txtUnit").innerHTML= "";`

both are not working .just getting error like this:

```
typeerror document.getelementbyid(...) is null
```

Comment: Show the html for the textbox

Comment: This question should be tagged with javascript rather than asp.net-mvc, as that is not relevant to the problem described or the code posted.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the element and look at the generated HTML in your browser. Probably you do not have a `txtUnit` there, as `txtUnit` is the server-side id. You need to refer to it as `txtUnit.ClientID`.

**EDIT:** More information

`getElementById` is null if the id was not found in your HTML. You must make sure that you have the id there and that your element was already created when you try to find it by id.